# Make: LDLIBS, deprecated?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the GNU Make documentation, variables LDLIBS and LOADLIBES are not documented in its corresponding [section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables). I've [read](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2005-01/msg00063.html) that these variables exists only for compatibility purposes, and that they are equivalents (same meaning). But, LDLIBS is still used spreadly.

Could it be said that LDLIBS is a deprecated variable, or would it be safe using it? If not, why is LDLIBS ignored by its documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GNU make manual says, in http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html:

*The following tables describe of some of the more commonly-used predefined variables. This list is not exhaustive*

Answer (score 38):

It seems `LOADLIBES` is deprecated, but `LDLIBS` is not. Thus, [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) says:

> `LDFLAGS`: Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to
>   invoke the linker, `ld`, such as `-L`. Libraries (`-lfoo`) should be
>   added to the `LDLIBS` variable instead.
>
> `LDLIBS`: Library flags or names given to compilers when they are
>   supposed to invoke the linker, `ld`. `LOADLIBES` is a deprecated (but
>   still supported) alternative to `LDLIBS`. Non-library linker flags,
>   such as `-L`, should go in the `LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: Many thanks for pasting this excerpt. I just need this differentiation between LDFLAGS and LDLIBS .

Comment: I had a very complex make system and along the way I double-guessed myself several times about the relationship of these variables... needless to say I found myself back here each time. Thank you brother. :) For any future visitor, it's as simple as you might guess it is - you put down flags (`LDFLAGS`) directing traffic before you do any construction (`LDLIBS`). Maybe you can think of a better analogy/mnemonic, it's deliberately uninspired.